# How to check visited link using jquery without using any plugin

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, visited

How to check visited link using jquery without using any plugin please help to solve this problem

Comment: what do you mean by visited link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Just check if it has the `:visited` property</strike>

```
if ($("a#theLink:visited").length) {
    //anchor tag with id of "theLink" has been visited
}
```

**edit**: Remy Sharp has made a [jquery plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/) to help detect visited links.

**edit2**  Look like this was security issue mozilla has fixed now, http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: Sorry for bumping old questions. But :visited doesn't work with jquery as far as I know, at least I can't get it to work. Anyone?

Comment: @Knarf Wow, you're right. I'm pretty sure this worked when I posted my answer. For anyone still looking, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RichardAndrewLee I updated my answer. Sorry it took as long.

Answer (score 2):

Remy Sharp jQuery plugin won't work anymore because it uses "getComputedStyle" which will always return false in mozilla as explain here : http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/